# SwiftUI Text: remove link highlighting

Tags: ios, swift, text, swiftui

Given the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            Text("https://lvmh.com")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following result:

[image]

**Desired outcome**

1. Make link color to be the same as the "Hello world" text color
2. Do not treat the text in the link as a tappable link, treat it just as a regular text.

**Follow-up question**

I'd like to apply the same behavior to the email strings, e.g.:

```
Text("r.topchii@corp.lvmh.com")
```

Should not be highlighted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution: use `Text(verbatim: )`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            Text(verbatim: "https://lvmh.com")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

Also solves the problem with the emails:

[image]